# prevent user to see video in url

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project for video tutorials like udemy. I encountered a problem that when the user clicks on the video link and copy in the URL field of browser, the video is shown to the browser even if he does not have a subscription. What is the way to prevent this issue?
for example if user has this link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploads/course_videos_2023-09/16950266052987331_first.mp4` and copy in URL field he can see the video

i try to make a middleware but it doesn't fix my problem

Comment: use spatie and implement `@can` or `@guest` or `@if($user->auth->subcription != NULL)` or whatever if clause you want

Comment: Don't place the videoname anywhere users/guests can see. Use the video's `id` (assuming you stored the info in a db), create a route that outputs the video based on that id. Check before if user is allowed to see it/has a subcsription

Comment: don't store the video on the public storage.

Comment: I think this may have more than a single approach. At first I do not store videos in public folders, in fact I do not store videos on my own server, but it depends in what infrastructure you are using. Lastly, You could protect your URLs with permissions or you could generate temporary signed routes for any video after check if given user is authorized to view it.

Answer (score -3):

Use a Validation on your website. I will suggest you to create a php file (subscribers.php) and create a validation query with the corresponding statements. then just put on the corresponding page (the one where you show the video) and put a require function (require 'subscribers.php'). If you need  a code example just show me or describe me your code and I'll help you out.
hope it helps.

Comment: That wouldn't work on the `.mp4` file itself - which is what OP asks about

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).